# A function as a parameter in UML

Tags: rest, uml, networking, swift-language, sequence-diagram

I was wondering what is the best way to represent a function that is passed as a parameter in UML. Because I want to create a sequence diagram of my current networking code in my Swift project and some functions pass a function as parameter to other functions. So I was wondering is their a standard way to describe it in UML, or can I use swift syntax in my UML.

Comment: May be of interest: [Functional programmers generally don't have a lot of use for diagrams](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2459397/7122).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a caller passes a function pointer to a callee, it is essentially defining a callback.  You may need to represent it as all of the following:

1. A member variable of the message payload
2. A member of the class receiving the payload, since the target of the callback is a type of state
3. A dependency from the callee to the caller
4. An interface on the caller (who will receive the callback)

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491501/how-to-represent-callback-in-uml-class-diagram).

Answer (score 2):

If you use a programming language in which functions are first-class citizens (Swift, for instance), they basically are variables. Therefore, you should consider them as variables, even in a UML diagram.